# ng serve fail after angular upgrade 8 to 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I upgrade my app from angular 8 to 9 by https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0

After that i try to **ng serve** but it's stuck at **13% building 25/26 modules 1 active ...s??embedded**

I have already tried to delete node_module then npm install again but it's does't work 
no error what do i have to do ?

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "tms-all-new",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.4",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.48",
    "angular-mydatepicker": "^0.4.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.10.0",
    "fullcalendar-scheduler": "^1.9.4",
    "leaflet-geosearch": "^2.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

angular.json:

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "adminlte3": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/adminlte3",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
              "src/assets/dist/css/adminlte.css",
              "src/assets/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css",
              "src/assets/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css",
              "src/assets/plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css",
              "src/assets/plugins/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.min.css",
              "src/assets/plugins/sweetalert2-theme-bootstrap-4/bootstrap-4.min.css",
              "src/assets/dist/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
              "./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css",
              "./node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/dist/scheduler.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/moment/moment.js",
              "./node_modules/moment/locale/th.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "src/assets/dist/js/adminlte.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.min.js",
              "src/assets/dist/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",
              "src/assets/dist/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.th.js",
              "./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js",
              "./node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/dist/scheduler.js",
              "./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/locale/th.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "adminlte3:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "adminlte3:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "adminlte3:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "adminlte3:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "adminlte3:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "adminlte3"
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

- delete node_modules folder.
- delete package-lock.json.
- ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty.

Comment: i tried it but still not working stuck at **13% building 25/26 modules 1 active ...s??embedded**